# Managing Cisco programmatically; Telnet vs SNMP?

Tags: network-programming, telnet, snmp, cisco

I was recently approached by a network-engineer, co-worker who would like to offload his minor network admin duties to a junior-level helpdesk tech.  The  specific location in need of management acts as an ISP for tenants on its single-site property, so there's a lot of small adjustments being made on a daily basis.

I am thinking it would be helpful to write him a winform app to manage the 32 Cisco devices, on-site.  I'd like to initially provide functionality which could modify access control lists, port VLAN assignments, and bandwidth limitations per VLAN... adding more to the list as its deemed valuable.

**My initial thought was to emulate a telnet session** with the network device; utilizing my network-engineer's familiarity with the command-line / IOS interaction.  Minimal time would be required to learn Cisco IOS conventions, myself.

**Though while searching for solutions, it appears that most people favor SNMP.**  That, or, their specific circumstances pushed them in the direction of SNMP.

I wanted to know if I've overlooked an obvious benefit of SNMP.  **Should I be using SNMP?  Why or why not?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SNMP is great for getting information *out* of a Cisco device, but is not very useful controlling the device.  (although technically, you *can* push a new config to a Cisco IOS device using a combination of SNMP and TFTP.  But sending a whole new config is a pretty blunt instrument for controlling your router or switch).

One of the other commenters mentioned the Cisco IOS XR XML API.  It's important to note that the IOS XR XML API is only available on devices that run IOS XR.  IOS XR is only used on a few of Cisco's high end carrier class devices, so for 99% of all Cisco routers and switches the IOS XR XML API is not an option.

Other possibilities are SSH or HTTP (many Cisco routers, switches, AP, etc. have an optional web interface).  But I'd recommend against either of those.   To my knowledge, the web interface isn't very consistent across devices, and a rather surprising number of Cisco devices don't support SSH, or at least don't support it in the base license.

Telnet is really the only way to go, unless you're only targeting a small range of device models.   To give you something to compare against, Cisco's own CiscoWorks network management software uses Telnet to connect to managed devices.

Comment: Furthermore, the Cisco web interface has, historically, been a ripe field for security issues and I, fr one, recommend disabling it by default, unless you absolutely must have it enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use SNMP, instead look at a little language called 'expect'.  it makes for a very nice expect/response processor for these routers.

Answer (score 3):

I have done a reasonable amount of real world SNMP programming with Cisco switches and find Python on top of Net-SNMP to be quite reasonable.  Here is an example, via Google books, of uploading a new Cisco configuration via Net-SNMP and Python:  [Cisco Switch Upload via Net-SNMP and Python](http://books.google.com/books?id=Y7RCCgjmowcC&lpg=PA225&ots=mgz1MnTtbF&dq=python%20for%20unix%20and%20linux%20cisco%20snmp&pg=PA225#v=onepage&q=&f=false).  I should disclose I was the co-author of the book referenced in the link.

Everyone's milage may vary, but I personally do not like using `expect`, and prefer to use SNMP because it was actually designed to be a "Simple Network Management Protocol".   In a pinch, expect is ok, but it would not be my first choice.  One of the reasons some companies use expect is that a developer just gets used to using expect.  I wouldn't necessarily chock up bypassing SNMP just because there is an example of someone automating telnet or ssh.  Try it out for self first.

There can be some truly horrible things that happen with expect, that may not be obvious as well.  Because expect waits for input, under the right conditions there be very subtle problems that are difficult to debug.  This doesn't mean a very experienced developer can't develop reliable code with expect, but it something to be aware of as well.

One of the other things you may want to look at is an example of using the multiprocessing module to write non-blocking SNMP code.  Because this is my first post to stackoverflow I cannot post more then one link, but if you google for it you can find it, or another one on using IPython and Net-SNMP.

One thing to keep in mind when writing SNMP code is that it involves reading a lot of documentation and doing trial and error.  In the case of Cisco, the documentation is quite good though.

Answer (score 1):

SNMP isn't bad but it may not be able to do everything you need it to do. Depending on the library you use and how it hides the details of interacting with SNMP you may have a hard time finding the correct parts of the MIB to change and even knowing what or how to change them to do what you want.

One reason not to use SNMP is that you can do all the configuration you need using the [IOS XR XML API](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios_xr_sw/iosxr_r3.2/xml/program/guide/xml_32.html). It could be a lot easier to bundle up the commands you want to send to the devices using that than to interact with SNMP.

Answer (score 1):

I've found SNMP to be a pain for management. If you just need to grab a little data it's great; if you need to change things or use if heavily it can be very time consuming. In my case I'm comfortable with the CLI so a Telnet approach works well. I've written some Python scripts to perform administrative tasks on various pieces of network gear using [Telnetlib](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-telnetlib.html)

Answer (score 1):

SNMP has quite a significant CPU hit on the devices in question compared to telnet; I'd recommend telnet wherever possible. (As stated in a previous answer, the IOS XR XML API would be nice, but as far as I know IOS XR is only deployed on high-end carrier grade routers).

In terms of existing configuration management systems, two commercial players are HP Opsware, and EMC Voyence. Both will probably do what you need. I'm not aware of many open source solutions that actually support deploying changes. ([RANCID](http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/), for example, only does configuration monitoring, not pre-staging and deploying config changes).

If you are going to roll your own solution, one thing I would recommend is sitting down with your network admin and coming up with a best-practice deployment model for the service he's providing (e.g. standardised ACL, QoS queue, and VLAN names; similar entries in ACLs that have the same function for different customers, etc.). Ensure that all the existing deployed config complies with this BP before you start your design, it will make the problem much more manageable. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote: before you reinvent the wheel writing another service provisioning system/network management system, try looking for existing ones. I know quite a lot of commercial solutions of various degrees of flexibility/functionality, but I am sure there are quite a lot opensource ones.

Comment: You're probably right.  But here, curiosity has convinced me to make an honest effort.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco has included menu options for helpdesk applications.  Basically you telnet to the box and it presents a nice clean menu (press 1, 2, 3).  For more info check this link:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/configfun/command/reference/frf001.html#wp1050026

Answer (score 0):

Another vote for expect.

Also, you don't want to allow configuration of your firewalls via either telnet or SNMP - ssh is the only way to go. The reason is that ssh encrypts its payload, and will not expose the privileged management credentials to potential interception.

If for some reason you cannot use ssh directly, consider connecting up an ssh-enabled serial console server to the firewall's console port and configuring it that way.